# How to Decrypt text in c# that is encrypted in react native using react-native-crypto-js?

Tags: c#, react-native, encryption

I am trying to decrypt the text in a c# application that I had encrypted in my react native application using react-native-crypto-js. This is the syntax I used to encrypt the text

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(doc.data().Content, 'my secret key')
```

Now I am trying to decrypt the this text in c# using the following code

```
static byte[] GenerateKey(string key, int keySize)
{
    int saltSize = keySize / 8;
    byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("random salt"); // Replace with a random salt

    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, salt, 1000);
    return pbkdf2.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
}
public string Decrypt(string encryptedText, string secretKey)
{

     // Replace with the encrypted text from the database
    string key = "my secret key";

    byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);

    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.KeySize = 256;
        aes.Key = GenerateKey(key, aes.KeySize);
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedBytes, 0, encryptedBytes.Length);

        string decryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);

        return decryptedText;
    }


}
```

But I am getting the error Padding is invalid. Can anybody help me to figure out what is wrong with this code?

Comment: "This is the syntax I used to encrypt" You show code calling decrypt after that sentence.

Comment: The key derivation functions differ (CryptoJS applies `EVP_BytesToKey()`) and the modes (CryptoJS applies CBC by default). Check the docs.